# button overflows inside the div

Tags: html, css

Sorry for a newbie question but i barely started css. I am trying to make a container that has an image and then some text below it and then a button. I want everything to be perfectly wrapped up in the container and I will have many such containers in the page.Below is the code i have but i cant get to work it.
Below is a snippet:

[image]

```
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="shop.css">
<div id="container">

    <div class="image">
        <div class="pic">
            <img src="images/itiem.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="label">
            <p> Item 1 </p>
            <form method="post" action="">
                <input type="submit" value="add">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="image">
        <div class="pic">
            <img src="images/itiem.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="label">
            <p> Item 1 </p>
            <form method="post" action="">
                <input type="submit" value="add">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</html>
```

css part:

```
body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

#container {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.image {
position: relative;
float: left;
margin: 4px;
padding: 10px;
width: 15%;
height: 30%;
background-color: gray;
padding: 0px;
margin: 10px;
}

.pic {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 80%;
background-color: red;
}

.label {
position: absolute;
top: 80%;
width: 100%;
height: 20%;
background-color: green;
padding: 0px;
}

p {
width: 100%;
height: 50%;
color: white;
background: pink;
}
```

Comment: Just a note: You forgot to end your body with </body>. Or are we missing some code?

Comment: It is because you are giving your container a height. Your options are changing the height or setting overflow to auto/scroll

Comment: how do I put that <p> tag and <form> tag inside the  div.label